# Usage: "Tell of", "report that" but is it only "relate that"? How about "relate of"?

Tags: synonyms, word-usage

Relate, as a synonym of report or tell (Roget's, 3rd ed., section 556.11): What are its usage limits?
Can one say

> Jane related that there had been a fire?

Just as one says

> Jane reported that there had been a fire?

Or is the structure similar to

> Jane told of the fire that had burned down the old barn.

Can one therefore say

> Jane related of the fire that had burned down the old barn?

I have searched (Google; Random House, Gardner), but I have not been succesful in pinpointing the usage of that  meaning of "relate".

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). What does your research about _relate_ and usual prepositions it collocates with show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ngram viewer [shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=related%20of%2Crelated%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crelated%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelated%20that%3B%2Cc0) that *relate of* has so declined in usage compared to *relate that* that the former is borderline non-idiomatic in modern parlance. (It's even more lopsided than it appears. A brief look through the results shows many false drops for *related of*.)

A non-scientific sampling of the older usage seems to show that the preposition *of* is mostly used with the passive voice, and mostly about people.  For instance from [*The Life of Henry Fielding, Esq.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mQ0yAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA57&dq=%22related%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW-4-EmPnOAhUMXB4KHQXSCgMQ6AEIQDAG#v=onepage&q=%22related%20of%22&f=false) by W Watson (1807):

It **is related *of***  him, that having perceived a trunk lying in the yard of an inn, he ordered one of his men, to go and speak with it.

However, it is possible to find active-voice uses with non-personal objects. From [*Travels through the southern departments of France*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AgA8AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA227&dq=%22related%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpt8HblfnOAhXDWh4KHUqzALI4ChDoAQhLMAg#v=onepage&q=%22related%20of%22&f=false) by A L Millin (1808):

> What I **have related *of*** the city of Aix, sufficiently attests the tastes of its inhabitants for literature and the arts.

If you relate of events today, you will sound stilted and archaic.